# How to get field values from package.json using process.env

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I want to access key/values set in `package.json`. I tried using `process.env.npm_package_*`.  I was able to access some fields like `process.env.npm_package_version` and a few more but most of then are `undefined`. Reading [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts#packagejson-vars) I think I should be able to access other fields.

A simplified version of my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "my-package-name",
  "version": "3.4.3",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/a5hk/repo",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "example": "node ./dist/index.js",
  }
}
```

For example `process.env.npm_package_homepage` returns `undefined`. This is called inside `/dist/index.js` which I run it using `example` script.

### UPDATE

The minimal example:

```json
{
  "name": "ntest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "example": "node ./index.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/a5hk/ntest.git"
  },
  "author": "a5hk",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/a5hk/ntest/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/a5hk/ntest#readme"
}
```

```javascript
console.log(process.env.npm_package_version)
console.log(process.env.npm_package_homepage)
console.log(process.env)
```

The second `console.log` return `undefined`.

Comment: npm v7? because nothing else comes to my mind..

Comment: @traynor npm version 8.3.0

Comment: well, or v8, then. I'd say it's something with version+OS combination, especially if it can't read only vars with special characters..

Comment: I am using wsl (Ubuntu),  I also tried Ubuntu on a VM, same results. I will try some other distro as well

Comment: why is it `dist`? are you building it using some tool? it should work https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-grothendieck-4xl2q?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, Yes I am using TypeScript. I have updated my question with a minimal example, not using any build tools or other tools. That minimal example also doesn't work.

Comment: @traynor, The minimal example works on Fedora 34 (node v14). But not on Ubuntu 20.4 (node v16 OR v14).

Comment: what happens when you try `"homepage": "string"`

Comment: `undefined` again

Comment: Not working on Fedora anymore, after a reboot.

Comment: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2609 and https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/main/implemented/0021-reduce-lifecycle-script-environment.md

Comment: Where do you want to parse the *package.json*? Just import it.

Answer (score 2):

Just import json file

```
   const p = require('package.json');
   console.log('version:', p.version);
   console.log('repository type:', p.repository.type);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-glade-sl5fql

Comment: I had to write `require('./package.json')` to get this to work as expected.